# Finding the point inside a triangle to minimize the total distance to three vertices

Tags: vector-analysis

Let $\mathbf a, \mathbf b, \mathbf c$ be three vectors. We want to minimize the function
$$
f(\mathbf r)=|\mathbf r-\mathbf a|+|\mathbf r-\mathbf b|+|\mathbf r-\mathbf c|.
$$
Now as usual we evaluate the gradient:
$$
\nabla f=\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf a}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf a|}+\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf b}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf b|}+\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf c}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf c|}=0.
$$
The sum of three unit vectors is zero, so the angle between any two of them is $\frac{2}{3}\pi$.

Question: can I find an expression of $\mathbf r$ in terms of $\mathbf a, \mathbf b, \mathbf c$? Please avoid writing the vectors into their components. I am looking forward to seeing a beautiful solution.

Comment: I'm not that well-versed with vectors, but is the [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) what you are looking for?

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated Yes, but the Wikipedia page is not giving what I am asking for.

Comment: This is $X(13)$ in the ETC https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html

Comment: a, b, c.  Are they vectors or vertices?

Comment: @herbsteinberg to be understood as $\overrightarrow {OA}=\mathbf{a}$ and triangle $ABC$.

Comment: If any of the triangle’s angles is greater than $\frac23\pi$, then there is no point at which the angles between the unit vectors are all equal to $\frac23\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A beautiful solution can indeed be derived, with all the symmetry preserved. It is suitably more involved, as expected.

Start with the zero gradient condition

$$
\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf A}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf A|}+\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf B}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf B|}+\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf C}{|\mathbf r-\mathbf C|}=0
$$

which leads to
$$\mathbf r =\frac{yz\mathbf A + zx\mathbf B + xy \mathbf C}{xy+yz+zx}
$$
where the scalers are $x=|\mathbf r-\mathbf A|$, $y=|\mathbf r-\mathbf B|$ and $z=|\mathbf r-\mathbf C|$. Because of the angles all being $2\pi/3$ between them, they satisfy, according to the cosine rule,
$$
a^2=y^2+z^2+yz\\
b^2=z^2+x^2+zx\\
c^2=x^2+y^2+xy
$$
where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the side lengths of the triangle, opposite of vertices A, B and C, respectively. Specifically, $a=|\mathbf B-\mathbf C|$, $b=|\mathbf C-\mathbf A|$ and $c=|\mathbf A-\mathbf B|$.

The joint equations above can be worked out, albeit in lengthy and tedious steps. Nonetheless, it produces the following solution
$$
\mathbf r =\frac{k_a\mathbf A + k_b\mathbf B + k_c \mathbf C}{(8/\sqrt{3})(a^2+b^2+c^2)K+32K^2}
$$
with the coefficients
$$
k_a=\left(a^2+ 4K/\sqrt{3}\right)^2 -(b^2-c^2)^2\\
k_b=\left(b^2+ 4K/\sqrt{3}\right)^2 -(c^2-a^2)^2\\
k_c=\left(c^2+ 4K/\sqrt{3}\right)^2 -(a^2-b^2)^2
$$
and $K$ representing the area of the triangle, i.e.
$$
K=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)}.
$$

Comment: What are $a,b,c$? Do you mean $a=|\mathbf a|$?

Comment: Side lengths of the triangle.

Comment: +1 Your answer looks beautiful but unfortunately I don't understand. user53153's standards are good enough for me in [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8567/what-is-the-standard-for-upvoting-an-answer-you-dont-know-is-correct).

Comment: This is the formula given in the ETC link I provided, "Barycentrics  a^4 - 2(b^2 - c^2)^2 + a^2(b^2 + c^2 + 4*sqrt(3)*Area(ABC)) : : "  (:: means cycle the variables a,b,c for the other two coefficients). Thanks for showing the steps to get to it.